# Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset In Mysql version 8.0.2

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, connection

This errors occurred only when stored procedure used otherwise in inline query works. Mysql version is 8.0.21 and framework used - Visual studio 2012 ultimate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM7Sn.png)
This errors occurred only when stored procedure used otherwise  inline query works. MySQL version is **8.0.21** and framework used - **Visual studio 2012** ultimate.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be it is mysql version dll issue.
remove current mysql dll references and add old one mysql version dll references.
i am not sure it is correct or not. but this works for me.